# Map.remove("x") removes from relevant "x" in Postgres Json column

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, linkedhashmap

I'm reading data from Postgres DB and then I need to remove one part of JSON data from the red data. But this has an impact on the database level because this even removes data from the DB level.

remove method

```
private static Map<String,Object> removePrivate(Object key) {
        try {
            Map<String, Object> keyMap = (Map<String, Object>) key;
            keyMap.remove("d");
            return keyMap;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.warn("no private component 'd' in private key",ex);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

The remove method is used here.

```
public List<Key> getKeys(URI controller, URI url, String type, String purpose, String reference, Long limit, boolean exportPrivate) {

        List<Key> keyList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<com.xxx.model.Key> keys = keyRepository.getKeys(controller, url, type, purpose, reference, limit);
        if (keys == null || keys.isEmpty()) throw new BadRequestException("No keys found for given settings");
        keys.forEach(key -> {
            try {
                Key k = modelMapper.map(key, Key.class);
                keyList.add(k);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("Parse exception {}", e.getMessage(),e);
                throw new BadRequestException("Invalid key format",e);
            }
        });

        if (!exportPrivate) keyList.forEach(key -> key.setKey(removePrivate(key.getKey())));
        return keyList;
    }
```

Is there any clear reason why removing the property "d" from the map has an effect on the database level and also it removes the "d" component from "keys" List, but it should remove only from "keyList" List.

Comment: Are you using a framework like Hibernate? Saving the data back?

Comment: @Bruno yes, I'm using spring Data JPA

Comment: Not clear what your `modelMapper` does, but it's possibly keeping the references to the `Map`, and then you'd be saving that later, affecting the data stored in the DB.

Comment: As a side-note, your choice of class names and variable names is confusing. Firstly, you have a `key.getKey()`, so a "key" contains a field called "key" too apparently, which seems to be of type `Map<String, Object>`, which then conflicts with the general terminology of `Map`s (where key/values have their own meanings). Essentially, in this short code sample, it seems the word "key" to mean at least 3 different kind of things...

Comment: If you are persisting that entity later all you have to do is make a clone of the list and modify that inside `getKeys` instead of operating on the original list.

Comment: @Bruno, there are two key dto, one is DB model and another is Response model, because this is a migration project and something cannot be modified, this is one of them. Also, there is a key object within Key DTO. What I'm trying to do is read the values from DB and parse it to response model using model mapper. And then , remove the "d" values within the key Object / Map which is inside the response (parsed) model.

Comment: @IgorFlakiewicz, I'm modifying the parsed object, not the value which is red from the DB. So, how this can cause an issue at the DB level. Also, after the operation, no DB operations are done. So, how can this impact the DB?

Comment: The issue is fixed. The reson for the issue is @Transaction annotation. I did use this for fixing some previous issues and due to this, the issue arise.

Comment: If you can't rename the fields/getters/methods, I'd suggest you make the variable names more explicit to distinguish between these types of objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause for the issue is `@Trasactional`. when I remove this the issue removed.
But it will be nice if someone can explain how `@Trasactional` can cause such an issue.

Comment: It could be because `@Transactional` will make it commit at the end of your method, whereas otherwise it wouldn't autocommit (this may depend on other settings). It can be a good thing to do read-only operations with `@Transactional` too (depending no the transactional/ACID properties you need in this code). You should probably look into what's keeping the references to your loaded data and check where it's saved (when it shouldn't).